# relevel many variables at once in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was a way in R to factor and relevel many variables in a DRY way. So lets say I had 15 dummy variables all coded with 0 and 1. R by default makes 0 the reference category how could I use factor and relevel functions to change the reference level for all 15 variables to 1. Can this be done in a loop? Something like:

```
varList <- list("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
                 "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15")

for (i in varList) {
    df$i <- factor(df$i)
    df$i <- relevel(df$i, ref = "1")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `[[` to access the variables this way:

```
for (i in varList) {
    df[[i]] <- relevel(factor(df[[i]]), ref = "1")
}
```

An alternative for applying the same transformation to many columns of a data frame is to use dplyr's `mutate_each` function:

```
library(dplyr)
var_vector <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
                "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15")

relev <- function(f) relevel(factor(f), ref = "1")

df <- mutate_each(df, funs(relev), one_of(var_vector))
```

If the columns you want to transform all follow a particular pattern, you could simply do something like:

```
# transform columns that start with V
df <- mutate_each(df, funs(relev), starts_with("V"))
# transform columns that have V then a number
df <- mutate_each(df, funs(relev), matches("^V\\d+"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `set` from `data.table` to change multiple columns in a loop.  It is very efficient as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5
setDT(df)
nm1 <- unlist(varList)

for(j in nm1){
   set(df, i=NULL, j=j, value=relevel(factor(df[[j]]), ref="1"))
}  

str(df)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(12)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.character(sample(0:9, 20*100, 
        replace=TRUE)), ncol=20))
```